# Flex list sort not working

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, filtering, flex4.5

My xml looks like this:

```
<feed title="'.$item->title.'" category="'.$categoryname.'">
<item category="'.$categoryname.'">
<title category="'.$categoryname.'">'.htmlspecialchars($item2->title).'</title>'
<description category="'.$categoryname.'">'.htmlspecialchars($item2->description).'</description>
<pubdate category="'.$categoryname.'">'.$item2->pubDate.'</pubdate>');
</item>
</feed>
```

And My filterfunction looks like this

```
private function handleCategories(event:Event):void{

            filter = event.currentTarget.selectedValue;
            feedData.filterFunction = categoryFilter;
            feedData.refresh();

        }
            protected function categoryFilter(item:XML):Boolean
            {
                return item.@category == filter;
                trace(filter);
}
```

When i load in my list it displays properly but when i filter (clickin a radiobutton) it keeps showing the same list. The trace you see above gives back the right category so that isn't the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something like

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:RadioButtonGroup change="handleCategories(event)" />
    <s:XMLListCollection id="feedData" />
</fx:Declarations>
```

or:

```
[Bindable]
private var feedData:XMLListCollection;
```

? And do you have any compiler or runtime warnings?

Comment: Thanx for the response, I had no warnings but it turned out the problem was at the dataside (PHP) not the flex... the filter didn't work because i forgot a quote in the attribute thx for willing to help!